# exceptions to trace.axd

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bug-tracking

I cant find useful description on tracing asp.net, so i am asking here - How do I send an exception from Controller (or View) to trace.axd but nothing else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show trace information only in trace.axd you should enable tracing in the web.config, set pageOutput = false, and not enable tracing on specific pages. To send exception info to the trace you will need to use Trace.Write when you catch the exceptions.